# Canvas. Нарисовать массив поэлементно с задержкой

Tags: javascript, canvas

Пытаюсь рисовать матрицу из квадратов в canvas в зависимости от количества элементов массива.
Задача состоит в том, чтобы отрисовывать квадраты постепенно, т.е сначала arr[0][0], потом после небольшой задержки arr[0][1] и так далее. 
У меня же рисуются все квадраты сразу. Даже если пытаюсь поставить задержку с помощью setTimeout(), после задержки появляются все квадраты, а не отрисовываются по одному.

Буду признателен за любые мысли по поводу этого. Спасибо.

Мой код:

```js
var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
if(drawingCanvas && drawingCanvas.getContext) {
    var context = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
    var arr = <?=json_encode($arr) ?>;
    console.log(arr);
    var x = 0;
    var y = 50;
    var timer = 1000;
    function animate(){
        context.stroke();
        }
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            context.rect(x, y, 50, 50);
            setTimeout(animate, timer);
            context.textAlign = "center";
            context.font = "12px Arial";
            context.fillStyle = "black";
            context.fillText(arr[i][j],x+25,y+28, 50);
            x = x + 50; 
            timer = timer+1000;
        }
        x=0;
        y=y+50;
    }
}
```

Comment: пробовали через `setInterval`?

Comment: Пробовал, эффект тот же. Помогло решение @Dantessss , с помощью bind. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно через `setTimeout`. Передаем функцию прорисовки, а чтобы переменные не потерялись оборачиваем функцию через `bind` и передаем все нужные переменные

```js
var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
if (drawingCanvas && drawingCanvas.getContext) {
  var context = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
  var arr = [
    ['a', 'b'],
    ['c', 'd']
  ];
  var x = 0;
  var y = 50;
  var c = 0;

  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.font = "12px Arial";
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      setTimeout(function(x, y,num) {
        context.strokeRect(x, y, 50, 50);
        context.fillText(num, x + 25, y + 28, 50);
      }.bind(this, x, y, arr[i][j]), (c++) * 500);
      x = x + 50;
    }
    x = 0;
    y = y + 50;
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```